# Chinese evergreen with clear droplet secretions on leaves

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, indoors, chinese-evergreen

Is my Chinese evergreen plant here in my office ok? I noticed some water droplet type secretions on the new leaves and on the undersides of some other leaves. Is this normal? An officemate said it could be from a bug.
It's hug and my favorite plant, please help!

Comment: Welcome! Could you please [edit] your post and add a picture or two? And as for all new users, let me point you to our [tour] and [help], which will give you a good introduction to how the site works.

Answer (score 1):

This is called [guttation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guttation) or 'the secretion of droplets of water from the pores of plants'.

It is not unusual and is not a sign of insects.  The liquid can be sticky and this is not a problem.

The plant's circulation system is drawing water from the soil up to the leaves and there is so much pressure it doesn't stop when it gets to leaves: a little bit leaks out.

This is more common when the plant is in high light.